# Material-UI Having More than One AppBar on a Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, appbar

Is there anyway to have more than a single material-ui AppBar on a page?

By default trying to put two AppBars on a page will cause them to overlap.  Was able to get around that by setting the second to have position sticky or by giving it a padding or margin top so that it no longer overlaps.  However that still causes a good deal of odd behavior.  Primarily with scrolling.  I've gotten it so that the second AppBar either is not extending out to the full width of the page or it is covering the top of the scrollbar.  Also while can have the rest of the page in a div or a Container that knows not to overlap with the first AppBar, it does not seem to be able to do the same with the second AppBar.  While can give a margin or padding to have eternal load show nothing overlapping, if I have it scroll directly to an element then they'll not overlap with the first AppBar but will overlap with the second AppBar.

Comment: Can you please add your code in codesandbox and share the URL till what you have achieve will help us find solution faster.

Comment: Code working on would not be able to show.  Was able to find a way of getting it to work (or at least someone else on the team was).  Will try to see if I can create an example agnostic to that codebase later.